# Как отправить сверстаный макет по почте?

Tags: google-chrome

Подскажите пожалуйста! Сверстала макет рассылки для одного журнала. Теперь мне нужно отправить ей материал таким образом, чтобы у нее сразу открылся макет а не браузер. Буду очень признательна!

Comment: Вы хотите отправить письмо, которое бы выглядело как Ваш свёрстанный макет?

Comment: Отправьте ей скриншот или как уже выше намекнул @edem отправьте макет как HTML письмо.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, лучший способ протестировать верстку письма - это отослать емейл. Я пользуюсь [mailChimp](https://login.mailchimp.com). Для тестовых рассылок (не массовых, а с ручным указанием адреса) он бесплатный. Загружаете туда архив со сверстанным письмом (html + папки с картинками), он формирует письмо и его можно рассылать.